# tag for "resolution"

Tags: discussion

Asking this question [Chord progressions : which note resolves to which note](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32884/chord-progressions-which-note-resolves-to-which-note),
I wanted to tag it as `resolution` which is not available. Will it be useful to add this tag?

Comment: Why not use [tag:voice-leading] as resolution is a big part of voice leading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not? It has been mentioned before (by mods) that tags are created when the community needs them. If we have questions that concern the resolution of notes, we will need a specific tag.

See [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1017/7356).

> Tags should come into play as they are needed.

Comment: "I wanted to tag it as `resolution`" isn't the same as it being needed, though.  I'm not an expert here, but based on Dom's comment and the accepted answer it looks like `voice-leading` has this covered.  If there is a need for a separate tag, please elaborate :)